# shuffle and swap column R

Tags: r, database, split, shuffle

I have a df of 2000 rows tennis matches with 10 columns of statics of the single match. All matches are sorted by DAY of the match and in ID1 the winner of the match.

What i need is to shuffle rows of my df (and this is not a problem because is quite simple) and randomly change position of ID1->ID2 and the stats in all the columns, for example to column A_1 -> column A_2, plus add a column when this is happening like "1" when the position of the columns is changed and "0" when all the columns are in the same position.

Here an example

```
DAY    ID1      ID2      A_1    A_2    B_1    B_2
1       10       20       4      6      10     2
2       5         4       0      2       5     1
3       23        34      5      10      2     8
4        4        12      6       4      3     1

EXPECTED RESULT
DAY    ID1      ID2      A_1    A_2    B_1    B_2    X
2       5         4       0      2       5     1     0
1       20        10      6      4       2     10    1
3        4        12      6       4      3     1     0
4       23        34      5      10      2     8     0
```

my first attempt was to do a sample and then substract rows in the sample from the main df. Then change every name columns in one of the 2 tables.

Comment: When you write `randomly change position of ID1->ID2 and the stats in all the columns`, do you mean you want to decide with some probability `p` whether or not to randomly shuffle the column values, per each row (like a coin flip, where some rows remain unshuffled and some get shuffled), or do you mean you definitely want to randomly shuffle the column values of every row (and then just keep track of which rows happen to have the shuffle leave the ordering unchanged)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work, in base `R`:

```
set.seed(16)
df1 <- apply(df[sample(nrow(df)),],1,function(x) {
  s <- sample(2)
  y <- c(x[1],x[s+1],x[s+3],x[s+5])
  y["X"] <- !all(s == 1:2)
  y})

df1 <- setNames(as.data.frame(t(df1)),c(names(df),"X"))
df1
#   DAY ID1 ID2 A_1 A_2 B_1 B_2 X
# 3   3  34  23  10   5   8   2 1
# 1   1  10  20   4   6  10   2 0
# 4   4  12   4   4   6   1   3 1
# 2   2   5   4   0   2   5   1 0
```

`sample(2)` shuffles the vector `1:2`. At each iteration a new instance of the sampling takes place.

It can be equal either to `c(1,2)` or `c(2,1)`.

Thus:

- `x[s+1]` is either `c(x[2],x[3])` or `c(x[3],x[2])`
- `x[s+3]` is either `c(x[4],x[5])` or `c(x[5],x[4])`
- `x[s+5]` is either `c(x[6],x[7])` or `c(x[7],x[6])`

And they all switch together or don't at all, as they all use the same value of `s`

Comment: is not the result that I expected. If the id1 became id2 and viceversa, columns must be inverted in this way: A1->A2 and viceversa
B1->B2 and viceversa. Values in A don't change in B columns.

Comment: EPIC! Could you please help me to understand this part?

y <- c(x[1],x[s+1],x[s+3],x[s+5])
  y["X"] <- !all(s == 1:2)

Comment: I added an explanation